# VSTO C# Word 2016: howto rename a document without saving it?

Tags: c#, ms-word, vsto

I need some help please.
I’m trying to rename the current word document before calling:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.CommandBars.ExecuteMso("FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment");
```

Actually I want to do so in order to change the name of the attachment, which otherwise is the default file name.
***The crucial point is that I don’t want to saveAs the document in new file.***
I had tried the following without success:

```
Globals.ThisAddIn.Application.ActiveDocument.ActiveWindow.Caption = "FOO";
```

Any idea please?
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not possible to rename a Word document without saving it. Save it (as a temp file, perhaps), close it, then delete it at a later point.

Comment: Thanks for replaying. Unfortunately that document is involved is another business logic which I will lose if I save it in a tmp file.
Otherwise, is there a way to change attachment name within the method ExecuteMso("FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment") ?

Comment: That I don't know. You might try researching in the direction of Outlook. I also don't know if it helps that it's possible to "extract" the document content using `Range.WordOpenXML` which can be streamed. Or copy the content to another (new) document, save and send that?

Comment: Maybe that’s the only way. But calling “FileEmailAsPdfEmailAttachment” is so much faster and easier then converting the active document to a pdf and create a new email…

Answer (score 0):

Ok, here is my solution to solve that problem, hoping that may helps someone else:

```
   private void buttonPDFToEmail_Click(object sender, RibbonControlEventArgs e)
{

   /* 
    * using Word = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
    * using Outlook = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Outlook; => if running a Word VSTO projet, need to add that reference in solution's references.
    */

    // Word application.
    Word.Application wApp = Globals.ThisAddIn.Application;

    // Word document.
    Word.Document wDoc = wApp.ActiveDocument;

    // instantiating Outlook application.
    Outlook.Application oApp = new Outlook.Application();

    // Generating the PDF filename.
    string filePDFName =
        (!String.IsNullOrEmpty(editBox_filePDFTitle.Text) & !String.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(editBox_filePDFTitle.Text)) ?
        editBox_filePDFTitle.Text :
        "PROJET";

    if (checkBox_addDate.Checked)
    {
        filePDFName += (char)32 + DateTime.Now.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy");
    }

    object fileName = @"C:\tmp\" + filePDFName;

    // Export activeDocument as PDF file.
    wDoc.ExportAsFixedFormat(
        fileName.ToString(),
        Word.WdExportFormat.wdExportFormatPDF
        );

     // Create a new email with no attachments.
    Outlook._MailItem oMailItem = (Outlook._MailItem)oApp.CreateItem(Outlook.OlItemType.olMailItem);

    // Adding our PDF file as attachement.
    oMailItem.Attachments.Add(fileName.ToString()+".pdf");

    // using System.IO;
    // Deleting the tmp PDF file.
    File.Delete(fileName.ToString() + ".pdf");

    // Displaying Outlook.
    oMailItem.Display(true);
}
```